# Finding if HABTM model association already exists

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-model

I have Users and Courses. They have a HABTM relationship that is manifested as Subscriptions (that's the table with user_id and course_id).

I need to have a condition on the Course page that checks if the user is subscribed to this course. I am not sure how to do that.

I have this $subscriptions set in the AppController in order to give me a menu of only subscribed courses in the nav:

```
$this->set('subscriptions', ClassRegistry::init('Subscription')->find('all', 
    array(
        'fields' => array('Course.id', 'Course.name'),
        'conditions' => array('Subscription.user_id =' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
        'recursive' => 1
    )));
```

My question: How do I check to see if the subscription exists already? I basically need to find if there's a subscription with user_id that's the same as logged in user, and a course_id the same as the current course I'm in.

Thanks!

Comment: When asking a question about a framework, it's always a good idea to include the version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?:

```
$exists = (bool) $this->Subscription->field('count', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
        'course_id' => $courseId
    )
));
```

**Side note:**  don't use `recursive`.  Set it to `public $recursive = -1;` in your AppModel, and then never set it again.  If you want to include "extra" data, use [Cake's Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) - it's consistent, and lets you specify exactly the data you want to pull instead of just guessing (which will cause issues in the long run).

Comment: @AD7six - I agree - good point/good code!  I've changed to match.

Comment: Hey Dave - thanks for the response. Just saw this and will let you know tomorrow if it worked. Thanks!